# IllegalStateException (Already attached) when opening NFC reader app

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, illegalstateexception, activity-lifecycle

I'm trying to develop an app that reads an NFC tag and displays the read data. I took most of the code from [a blog](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278) but I'm getting an error when I run the application since I am trying to integrate it with the slider application.

Here are my errors and my code below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.jeffk11.tag, PID: 20123
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jeffk11.tag/com.example.jeffk11.tag.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2137)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:104)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:317)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:88)
                      at com.example.jeffk11.tag.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Code:

```
package com.example.jeffk11.tag;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.util.Log;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private TextView mTextView;
    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";
    public static final String TAG = "NfcDemo";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_explanation);

        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;

        }

        if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mTextView.setText("NFC is disabled.");
        } else {
            mTextView.setText(R.string.explanation);
        }

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

            String type = intent.getType();
            if (MIME_TEXT_PLAIN.equals(type)) {

                Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                new NdefReaderTask().execute(tag);

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Wrong mime type: " + type);
            }
        } else if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

            // In case we would still use the Tech Discovered Intent
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
            String searchedTech = Ndef.class.getName();

            for (String tech : techList) {
                if (searchedTech.equals(tech)) {
                    new NdefReaderTask().execute(tag);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        /**
         * It's important, that the activity is in the foreground (resumed). Otherwise
         * an IllegalStateException is thrown.
         */
        setupForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        /**
         * Call this before onPause, otherwise an IllegalArgumentException is thrown as well.
         */
        stopForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        /**
         * This method gets called, when a new Intent gets associated with the current activity instance.
         * Instead of creating a new activity, onNewIntent will be called. For more information have a look
         * at the documentation.
         *
         * In our case this method gets called, when the user attaches a Tag to the device.
         */
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * @param activity The corresponding {@link Activity} requesting the foreground dispatch.
     * @param adapter  The {@link NfcAdapter} used for the foreground dispatch.
     */
    public static void setupForegroundDispatch(final AppCompatActivity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getClass());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[1];
        String[][] techList = new String[][]{};

        // Notice that this is the same filter as in our manifest.
        filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
        filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        try {
            filters[0].addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
        } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Check your mime type.");
        }

        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
    }

    /**
     * @param activity The corresponding {@link BaseActivity} requesting to stop the foreground dispatch.
     * @param adapter  The {@link NfcAdapter} used for the foreground dispatch.
     */
    public static void stopForegroundDispatch(final AppCompatActivity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity);
    }


    class NdefReaderTask extends AsyncTask<Tag, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Tag... params) {
            Tag tag = params[0];

            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef == null) {
                // NDEF is not supported by this Tag.
                return null;
            }

            NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();

            NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
            for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
                if (ndefRecord.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN && Arrays.equals(ndefRecord.getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT)) {
                    try {
                        return readText(ndefRecord);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported Encoding", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        private String readText(NdefRecord record) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        /*
         * See NFC forum specification for "Text Record Type Definition" at 3.2.1
         *
         * http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/
         *
         * bit_7 defines encoding
         * bit_6 reserved for future use, must be 0
         * bit_5..0 length of IANA language code
         */

            byte[] payload = record.getPayload();

            // Get the Text Encoding
            String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";

            // Get the Language Code
            int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;

            // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");
            // e.g. "en"

            // Get the Text
            return new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                mTextView.setText("Read content: " + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call the `onCreate` method of the super-class (`AppCompatActivity`) multiple times in your own `onCreate` method. Don't do that. `super.onCreate()` must be called only once (typically this is done at the beginning of your activity's `onCreate` method. So simply remove the second occurence of

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```