# Unable to start activity ( java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an app with five buttons on my home screen. On pressing each button a new activity pops up.

When I am hitting the second button it displays error:

```
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{debuggers.os_project/debuggers.os_project.SJF}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached**
```

The first button is working fine. Till yet I have coded only for two buttons.

My main_activity.java is:

```
package debuggers.os_project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static Button fcfs;
private static Button sjf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fcfs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fcfs);
    sjf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sjf);
    fcfs.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FCFS.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}

public void onSJF(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),SJF.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: Giving your variables meaningful names would greatly help in reading your code...

Comment: Share the code for SJF activity. I think the problem lies there. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384888/java-lang-illegalstateexception-already-attached

Comment: @PavanPatil You were right the problem was in SJF activity. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
public void onSJF(View view){
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SJF.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

To start a new activity, you pass the current activity class as the first argument and the next activity class as the second argument to the Intent new instance!

Please try and see if this works;

Answer (score 0):

on click listener should look like this:

```
fcfs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fcfs);
fcfs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FCFS.class);
         startActivity(intent);
});
```

And your didn't use your method.
You can build one method and can be use by all the button:

```
public void method_for_intent (Class your_class){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, your_class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in your onCreate, should look like this finally:

```
Button fcfs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fcfs);
Button sjf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sjf);
fcfs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         method_for_intent(FCFS.class)
    });
sjf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         method_for_intent(SJF.class)
    });
```

And you might call `oncreate` multiple times in your new activities.
[IllegalStateException (Already attached) when opening NFC reader app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152416/illegalstateexception-already-attached-when-opening-nfc-reader-app)

(You can put your on click listener into the method too)
Haven't test the code.
Tall me if I have anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`super.onCreate()` might be called twice in your Activity. Check that you are not doing that by mistake.

If you deep dive into the Activity/FragmentActivity code, you can see the error is related to its relationship with the FragmentManager:

Your Activities will normally inherit from AppCompatActivity that inherits from FragmentActivity:

```
// FragmentActivity
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mFragments.attachHost(null /*parent*/);
    ...
}
```

and

```
// FragmentController
public void attachHost(Fragment parent) {
    mHost.mFragmentManager.attachController(mHost, mHost /*container*/, parent);
}
```

and

```
// FragmentManager
public void attachController(FragmentHostCallback host, FragmentContainer container, Fragment parent) {
    if (mHost != null) throw new IllegalStateException("Already attached");
    mHost = host;
    mContainer = container;
    mParent = parent;
}
```

BOOM!