# FragmentManager.ensureExecReady java.lang.IllegalStateException - FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-developer-api

This is the Firebase Crashlytics log.

I can't determine the specific line of code causing the error. It appears to be related to the Google Library, but the details don't make sense.

```
    # Crashlytics - Stack trace
# Application: ---
# Platform: android
# Version: 1.5.6 (33)
# Issue: e4d786617743dc6c4c66420d3cb05a6a
# Session: 65AA8709032F00015585A918707B2EE0_DNE_0_v2
# Date: Fri Jan 19 2024 16:28:26 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.hippo/com.woohouse.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2994)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1766)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)

Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:91)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:11)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:10)
       at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.updateFragmentMaxLifecycle(FragmentStateAdapter.java:187)
       at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer$3.onStateChanged(FragmentStateAdapter.java:3)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:18)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:329)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:329)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:50)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:9)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:2)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:121)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:121)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:121)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:121)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:138)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:62)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:62)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:36)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:150)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:150)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:150)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:138)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:62)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:62)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:36)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:32)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:32)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:32)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7247)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1766)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)

Firebase Background Thread #1:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1087)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(CustomThreadFactory.java:438)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Firebase Background Thread #3:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1087)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(CustomThreadFactory.java:438)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

awaitEvenIfOnMainThread task continuation executor1:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1087)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:5)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

FinalizerDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:108)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

pool-7-thread-1:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1087)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

queued-work-looper:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:180)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

Firebase Background Thread #2:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1087)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(CustomThreadFactory.java:438)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Crashlytics Exception Handler1:
       at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
       at java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1588)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.populateThreadsList(CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.java:229)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.populateExecutionData(CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.java:229)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.populateEventApplicationData(CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.java:229)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.captureEventData(CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.java:229)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.SessionReportingCoordinator.persistEvent(SessionReportingCoordinator.java:229)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.SessionReportingCoordinator.persistFatalEvent(SessionReportingCoordinator.java:229)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$2.call(CrashlyticsController.java:229)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$2.call(CrashlyticsController.java:229)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker$3.then(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zze.run(zze.java:62)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:5)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Favorite.anteater:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:180)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

Firebase Blocking Thread #0:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1086)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(CustomThreadFactory.java:438)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Firebase-Messaging-Init:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1120)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1087)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(zza.java:35)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor.run(DefaultExecutor.java:142)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

ScionFrontendApi:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2101)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1086)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

ReferenceQueueDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:183)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:108)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

GmsDynamite:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zza.run(zza.java:6)

FinalizerWatchdogDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:302)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:282)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:108)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Firebase-Messaging-Topics-Io:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1120)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1087)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(zza.java:35)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.startup1:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1087)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:5)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Measurement Worker:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
       at m.jc.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@234914013@23.49.14 (040400-0):71)

Firebase Background Thread #0:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2059)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1087)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1147)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(CustomThreadFactory.java:438)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

glide-active-resources:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources.cleanReferenceQueue(ActiveResources.java:8)
       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources$2.run(ActiveResources.java:8)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources$1$1.run(ActiveResources.java:7)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: The error indicates that you've passed the wrong FragmentManager to your `ViewPager2`'s adapter. Please include where you create and set your adapter

Comment: can you post the relevant code too?

Answer (score 1):

The crash log mentions that your Android application is getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` due to [`FragmentManager`](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager) already executing transactions.
That typically occurs when you try to perform a fragment transaction (like adding, replacing, or removing a fragment) at an inappropriate time in the fragment's lifecycle or when the `FragmentManager` is not in a state to handle such transactions.
For instance, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42852240/6309) suggests `super.onCreate()` might be called twice in your `Activity`.

So make sure fragment transactions are not executed immediately during `Activity` lifecycle methods like `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, or `onResume()`.
Instead, you can schedule them to be executed after the current lifecycle phase is complete.

For instance:

```java
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_your);

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
            // Perform your fragment transaction here
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, YourFragment.newInstance());
            transaction.commit();
        });
    }
}
```

[`Handler.post()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#post(java.lang.Runnable)) is used to schedule the fragment transaction after `onCreate()` has completed. That should avoid any `IllegalStateException`, making sure the `FragmentManager` is ready to execute the transaction.